# How to avoid writing empty json files in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using dataframewriter to write a compressed JSON from a spark job like shown below.

```
dataframe.write.option("compression", "gzip").json(outputFileFolder)
```

Sometimes, I see the output contains empty files if the dataframe contains only few rows. Is there a way to avoid writing empty files?

Thanks!

Comment: You can do it by reducing the number of partitions. Use coalesce transformation, then save the contents in a file. If your data is not huge,you can coalesce the dataframe into 1 partition and then use write API to save.

Comment: However, if your collection is very large, what you probably want to do is partition your data so that it's saved in even chucks across your cluster.